# Individual IDs of Repeater child in QML

Tags: qt, qml, repeater

I was wondering if it is possible to assign individual IDs to the child of a repeater in QML?

For example, if my repeater was to create 10 rectangles, how do I assign each of them a unique id? e.g. rec1, rec2, etc.

Comment: no, it is not possible

Comment: Why do you need individual ids?, it seems to me that you have a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Give an id to the repeater and use `.itemAt(index)` to reference individual objects. Apart from this, I can't guess what you're trying to accomplish. I agree with @eyllanesc that you seem to have an XY problem. Perhaps describe your overarching goal + provide code/examples? Also make sure to check out [the SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and _[how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_.

Answer (score 3):

As already said above [id](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#the-id-attribute) is not a regular property and cannot be set or changed at runtime. You cannot reference this attribute, for example the following code will not work:

```
console.log(obj.id);
```

The nearest analogue of `id` from C++ is a variable name:

```
auto id = new Object();
```

when you can reference the name but cannot set or change it.

As for the issue, you can reference an item using `objectName`, or by using some specified access function, for example:

```
Row {
    id:row
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    spacing: 5
    Repeater {
        id: container
        model: 10
        Text {
            text:"item" + index
            objectName: "item" + index
        }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            container.itemAt(5).text = "changed1";
            findChild(row, "item6").text = "changed2";
        }

        function findChild(obj, name) {
            for(var i = 0;i < obj.children.length;i ++){
                if(obj.children[i].objectName === name)
                    return obj.children[i];
            }
            return undefined;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add this property to any QML object that requires a unique id:

```
readonly property string uniqueId: `${this}`.substring(`${this}`.indexOf("(0x") + 2).replace(")", "")
```